# Должны ли метки классов при классификации и регрессии "SciKit-Learn" быть отсортированы

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Есть метки двух классов искомого "0" и негативного "1".
Они имеют следующий вид:

```
print(y)
#[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]
```

Нужно ли изменять данные, чтобы сначала шли данные искомого класса, а потом негативного? То есть так:

```
#[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйта вопрос. Что такое `метки классов`? Как вы получили  `y`? и что вы собираетесь делать дальше с полученными данными?

Comment: Поправил заголовок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Их не просто не нужно сортировать - [это даже может быть вредно](https://www.google.com/search?q=machine+learning+why+do+we+shuffle+data). Обычно данные "тасуют" случайным образом перед обучением модели.

Comment: Спасибо! Просто в примерах данные по ирисам Фишера, а там они друг за другом идут, поэтому возник логический вопрос, не специально ли это сделано.